# Running meteor app on Windows from MacOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I got a Meteor project from a friend who develops on MacOS.

When trying to run it, I get:

> This project uses METEOR@1.0.2.1, which isn't available on Windows. To
>   work with this app on all supported platforms, use meteor update
>   --release METEOR@1.2.1 to pin this app to the newest Windows-compatible release.

When running it, I get:

> While checking for cfs:gridfs@0.0.27: no compatible binary file
>   found...

Then, when I try to override (use run instead of update), without actually updating, it starts proxy and Mongo, but then breaks at, but skips the first error

> While building package npm-container: error: No plugin known to handle
>   file '../../packages.json'. If you want this file to be a static
>   asset, use addAssets instead of addFiles; eg,
>   api.addAssets('../../packages.json', 'client').

I read that this error is fixed by updating meteorhacks, but when I try to, I get the Meteor version conflicts (see very first error) and I have no idea how to break out of the loop.

Can someone shine some light on how to fix any of these error?

Comment: I'd bet that first error is causing the other two since it explicitly states that 1.0.2.1 is not available on Windows.

Comment: Any ideas how I can update it?

Comment: You should ask your friend to do it, as there are many [breaking changes](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Breaking-changes-in-Meteor-1.2) caused by upgrading from 1.0.2.1 to 1.2.1